# Graph partitioning with parts of equal size

Tags: algorithms, graphs

> Partition an undirected graph of $n$ nodes into $k$ subgraphs so that total vertices inside all subgraphs is maximum.
>
> Restriction: all subgraphs have the same number of nodes (so $k$ divides $n$); $k$ is given initially.

I'd like to receive pointers to the solution as well as papers or blogs related to or expanding on it.

Comment: You might want to add the appropriate definitions to make sure we know what exact problem you are referring to.

Comment: Thank for pointing out. I've added the restriction.

Comment: You probably mean "total edges", not "total vertices". In any balanced partition, the total number of vertices in each part is always n/k.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a special case of [graph partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition). When $k=2$, the problem is known as *minimum bisection*, and is NP-complete.